# How can I use a common public variable from some unknown classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did not post this on unity forum because I think is more c# related then unity related.
I am wanting to shot an enemy. 
My enemy is or a player or an enemy AI.
Player has PlayerCombatSystem and enemy Ai has EnemyCombatController.I am using Object variable to take one of this two scripts using

```
GetComponent<ScriptName>()
```

collider means the object I am colliding with

What can i do to add the value I am storing in PlayerCombatSystem or EnemyCombatController for damage? Damage is a public value

This was my two attempts to fix thix

```
float gotDamage = shotterDamage * (100 / (100 + enemy.GetInstanceID.

float gotDamage = shotterDamage * (100 / (100 + enemy.damage;


Object enemy;
float shotterDamage;

if(shotter.GetComponent<PlayerCombatSystem>() != null)
{
    shotterDamage = shotter.GetComponent<PlayerCombatSystem>().damage;
}
else if(shotter.GetComponent<EnemyCombatController>() != null)
{
    shotterDamage = shotter.GetComponent<EnemyCombatController>().damage;
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("ERROR 0");
}

if (collision.GetComponent<PlayerCombatSystem>() != null)
{
    enemy = collision.GetComponent<PlayerCombatSystem>();
}
else if (collision.GetComponent<EnemyCombatController>() != null)
{
    enemy = collision.GetComponent<EnemyCombatController>();
}

float gotDamage = shotterDamage * (100 / (100 + enemy
```

Comment: make them both inherit from the same base class

Comment: and it will appear? I am not familiar with how it works

Comment: just to understand: in `enemy` you want a field in the Inspector where you can reference both a `PlayerCombatSystem` or a `EnemyCombatController` and both have a public float Damage?

Comment: yes. They have.

Answer (score 1):

make a shared base class like e.g.

```
// abstract just makes sure this can't be instanced 
// directly but only inherited types
public abstract class CombatBase : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float Damage; 
}
```

and than make your two scripts inherit from this base class instead

```
public class PlayerCombatSystem : CombatBase 
{
    // inherits Damage and everything implemented in CombatBase
    // so remove it here

    // and here you can extend it with its speicifc behaviour
}
```

and

```
public class EnemyCombatController : CombatBase 
{
    // inherits Damage and everything implemented in CombatBase
    // so remove it here

    // and here you can extend it with its speicifc behaviour
}
```

than in your script you can simply use a

```
CombatBase enemy;

...

// this will also find either PlayerCombatSystem 
// or EnemyCombatController since they are both of type 
// CombatBase
enemy = collision.GetComponent<CombatBase>();

...

float gotDamage = shotterDamage * (100 / (100 + enemy.Damage);
```

Comment: thanks, I am not able to change my code now but I will check as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a constructor, for example:

```
public class EnemyCombatController : MonoBehaviour
{

public PlayerCombatSystem constructorPlayerCombatSystem ;

//your code

//...

//Damage has changed in the other script (PlayerCombatSystem)



float gotDamage = shotterDamage * (100 / (100 + enemy.constructorPlayerCombatSystem.Damage);

}
```

Creating a constructor of another class is used when you want to use a variable in both classes

I did not understand very well the operation of your code, but simplifying a bit, I infer that the game is carried out in another or other scripts and when the shock is detected (or hit) the variable Damage changes.

Assuming that this variable is in the script that the player has, you want to use it in the script that has the enemy (or the opposite) (or that the variable is in another script and you want to use it in the other two), you can make a variable of the type of the other class and use it in that class.

remember that you must reference the object that contains the class in the inspector

I hope it helps you, or tell me if I understood something wrong about your problem